# How to compare two histograms and prove that there is a match between the two histograms?

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

i want to compare two histogram and show that the two histograms matches together.
I have in mind of reading the two images
Show theirs histograms and then using a function or any code to show that hist1=hist2.

Comment: There's no question here. Also, this has nothing to do with [tag:matlab-guide], the GUI design tool in MATLAB. I'm sure you meant to use the [tag:matlab] tag instead.

Comment: Just because two histograms match doesn't mean that the images themselves match.  That's the fallacy when comparing bins of histograms together - they don't take the spatial orientation and composition of pixels into account.  You need to use something else to determine if two images are similar... in fact, this is still an unsolved problem.  There are no methods that will get this 100% correct currently.

Comment: Hello sir, i have an assigment where i have to do gui in matlab i need a to load any images and detect the noise models with the message box returning the type of noise. Im actually looking for a way to detect the noise models applied on any image loaded in my program. Can you suggest me some steps to do that?. Or some methods? I have planned to find an uniform part on image and see how histogram will look like. And then make some comparaison with another type of image with the noise i need and see wether they can match? If they match then a messagebox will display the noise models.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use normalized euklid distance as a similarity measure:

```
x0 = randn(1000,1);
x1 = randn(1000,1);
nbins = 100;
y0=hist(x0,nbins);
y1=hist(x1,nbins);
similarity = 1-norm(y1-y0)/norm(y0)
```

Comment: Thank. For your answer. Mr martin.

Comment: Im using the code this code  x0 = randn(1000,1);
x1 = randn(1000,1);
nbins = 100;
y0=hist(x0,nbins);
y1=hist(x1,nbins);
similarity = 1-norm(y1-y0)/norm(y0)